# Get multiple image from variable by ajax

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'am trying to get multiple images from variable have multiple images but i only get one.

the variable is $src.

// the frontend code

```
              foreach ( $chapter['storage'][ $in_use ]['page'] as $page => $link ) {
                $host = $chapter['storage'][ $in_use ]['host'];
                $src  = $host . $link['src'];

                }
                $this->send_json( 'success', '', $src );
```

// ajax code

```
$(function(){
$('.entry-content .entry-content_wrap').ready(function(){
    var navigation = $('.single-chapter-select').find('option:selected').data('navigation');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',

        url: manga.ajax_url + '?' + navigation,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            var imag_link = data.data.data;
                console.log(imag_link);
                $('.entry-content .entry-content_wrap').html('<img style="margin: -6px;width: 89%;pointer-events: none;" class="wp-manga-chapter-img" src="' + imag_link + '">');
        },
       })
    })
  })
```

Comment: the $src will be replaced by a new value in the iteration

Comment: how can i get all image from the loop to ajax

Comment: Make an empty array before the loop starts, and keep adding $src  to it when you loop. Then return the array in the send() function. The amend the JavaScript to also loop

Comment: I get the value of the loop in the console.log(value); but when i try to add value to $('.entry-content_wrap').html('<img src="' + value + '">'); i get one image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PHP code you need to collect all of the URLs in an array and return it.

```php
$sources = [];
foreach ( $chapter['storage'][ $in_use ]['page'] as $page => $link ) {
    $host = $chapter['storage'][ $in_use ]['host'];
    $src  = $host . $link['src'];
    $sources[] = $src;
}
$this->send_json( 'success', '', $sources );
```

In frontend you should loop over the sources and attach them to your html as you wish.